# Unable to read Django FileField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-file-upload

I am trying to read from *Django* **Filefield**, as can be seen in my Django Model:

```
import os
import win32api

from django.db import models
from custom.storage import AzureMediaStorage as AMS

class File(models.Model):
    '''
    File model
    '''
    file = models.FileField(blank=False, storage=AMS(), null=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    remark = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")

class File_Version(File):
    """
    Model containing file version information
    """
    version = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="")

    @property
    def get_version(self):
        """
        Read all properties of the given file and return them as a dictionary
        """   

        props = {'FileVersion': None}

        # To check if the file exists ?
        ### This returns FALSE
        print("Is the file there? ", os.path.isfile(str(File.file)) )

        # To get file version info
        fixedInfo = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(str(File.file), '\\')
        print("FixedInfo: ", fixedInfo)
```

But *os.path.isfile()* keeps returning **False**. How do I read from FileField, into my custom model ?

And moreover, the line *fixedInfo*, gives me the error:

> pywintypes.error: (2, 'GetFileVersionInfo:GetFileVersionInfoSize',
>   'The system cannot find the file specified.')

Comment: what is the value of `str(File.file)`?

Comment: Printing them gave me :                                                                                  File Field:  <django.db.models.fields.files.FileDescriptor object at 0x000001E7E2F59B00>
File Field Type:  <class 'django.db.models.fields.files.FileDescriptor'>

Comment: What is this? `custom.storage import AzureMediaStorage`?

Comment: That's to define my custom storage (Azure). I store the files in blob storage on Azure!!

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.isfile` returns whether the filepath is pointing to a file (as opposed to a directory, for instance).  `File.file` is pointing to a `models.FileField` object; the current code will always return `False`. I suppose you would want `File.file.path` to get the actual absolute filepath for the file.

Comment: Hey!! When I try File.file.path, I get the error: AttributeError: 'FileDescriptor' object has no attribute 'path'

Answer (score 0):

In your model definition you may add:

```py
class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()
    ...
    ...

    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)
```

Or you may try:

from django.core.files.storage import default_storage

Use:
1) FieldFile.name:

The name of the file including the relative path from the root of the Storage of the associated FileField.

2) default_storage.exists(path)

Return True if a file referenced by the given name already exists in the
storage system, or False if the name is available for a new file.

Hope this works!

Comment: Hey! I continue to get the File not found error. Also, printing File.file_name returns: File_Name Field:  <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x000002EA91953080>
File Name Type:  <class 'django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute'>

Comment: what you probably want is `os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.file.name)`

Comment: @Abhishek Using default_storage.exists(path) gives the error: AttributeError: 'DeferredAttribute' object has no attribute 'replace' . (This can be understood better, with reference to the error in my above comment)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a different storage provider for your files, you need to use the methods of that storage provider to query the file object.

`os.path.isfile` and `win32api.GetFileVersionInfo` only work for the local file system.

Comment: I suspected this, but thanks for pointing out. But I have configured Django to communicate with Azure. So, how exactly should I go about solving this ?